# No suitable constructor found error occuring inside extended subclass Constructors

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have been recently working on a project in which I have ended up using a class which extends another class (namely Connection and Transfer). The error I have been receiving was "error: no suitable constructor found for Connection(no arguments)." The error was given at the lines of the beginnings of the constructors in Transfer.

```
class Connection {
    List<Station> connectedStations = new ArrayList();
    int length;
    boolean isTransfer = false;

    public Connection(Station s1, Station s2, int distance) {
        /* Code in here */
    }
    public Connection(Station s1, Station s2) {
        /* Code in here */
    }

}
```

and Transfer:

```
class Transfer extends Connection {
    List<Line> linesTransfer = new ArrayList();
    boolean isTransfer = true;
    public Transfer(Station s1, Station s2, int distance, Line l1, Line l2) {
        /* Code in here */
    }
    public Transfer(Station s1, Station s2, Line l1, Line l2) {
        /* Code in here */
    }

}
```

In my main class, I have several functions which make use of these. I continue to get the same error if all but this function is commented out:

```
public static Station findInStations(int iD) {      
    for(Entry<Integer, Station> stat : stations.entrySet()) {
        if(stat.getValue().id == iD) { 
            return stat.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This basically finds the station you are looking for in the instance variable hashmap for the main class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Transfer` extends `Connection`, when `Transfer` is constructed a constructor for `Connection` must be invoked before construction of `Connection` can proceed. By default, Java will use the no-args constructor if one exists. However, `Connection` doesn't have a no-args constructor (because you explicitly defined a constructor, and then didn't explicitly define a no-args constructor) and therefore you must explicitly specify a constructor of `Connection` to use.

Thus, you should write:

```
class Transfer extends Connection {
    List<Line> linesTransfer = new ArrayList();
    boolean isTransfer = true;
    public Transfer(Station s1, Station s2, int distance, Line l1, Line l2) {
      super(s1, s2, distance);
      /* Code in here */
    }
    public Transfer(Station s1, Station s2, Line l1, Line l2) {
      super(s1, s2);
      /* Code in here */
    }
  }
```

This is how you explicitly invoke a constructor for the base class.

Comment: so you have to create the object as a Connection before making it a specialized type: a Transfer. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: @MLavrentyev That's typically how people think of it, yes.